# Symfony2 console command arguments vs options when to use what

Tags: symfony

I would like to know of any guidelines to use input argument vs input options for passing in data to the symfony console command.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html

I think arguments are to be used when the passed data is required for the command to execute, else use options.

Can you guys throw more light on this? What's the standard ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation thoroughly? The sections ["Using command options"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#using-command-options) and ["Using command arguments"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#using-command-arguments) have everything you need to know, e.g. *"Unlike arguments, options are not ordered (meaning you can specify them in any order) and are specified with two dashes"*.

Comment: What if order does not matter. An argument can be passed as option in any order using options. Then what is the rational to use command options vs arguments.

Comment: Use options for things like --clear --debug --num 10, etc. You can't use arguments for that so you use options.

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest use Arguments when You want to specify excecution-required values, like:

```
bin/console vendor:delete-entity 120
```

but not

```
bin/console vendor:delete-entity --id=120
```

You can use Options, when You want to **alter** the default execution scenario, like:

```
bin/console vendor:delete-entity 120 --dump-sql
```

or

```
bin/console vendor:bulk-create something --batch-size=100
```